# How to Store multiple int user input in one into STACK in JAVA

Tags: java, stack, java.util.scanner

I'am very new to programming and I'm not sure what I've been doing. I'm creating a program that allows us user to input multiple int values in single line and store it to stack.

For example

Enter numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6

But I found out that the only scanner only get the first number. how can I be able to get all the numbers in one line and store it in a stack.

This is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackPractice {    

    public static void main(String[] args)  {    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements to place on the stack [1-10]:");
        int stackSize = sc.nextInt();
        Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

        System.out.println("Enter " + stackSize + " element(s):");
        for( int i = 0; i < stackSize;i++){
        while(sc.hasNextInt() && i < stackSize){
            stack.push(sc.nextInt());

                int number = sc.nextInt();
                stack.push(number);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stack);            
    }
}
```

Comment: please put all the relevant information in the question, and be clear about your question. what is(n't) working?

Comment: sorry sir, my problem is I don't know how to store multiple int inputs from scanner in stack

Comment: you are still not clear for those who don't know your assignment. What and how is it supposed to work? as for the output expected, edit it in the question, not in an external link

Comment: The code in the question now has some obvious problems: there's a `for` loop and a `while` loop nested inside, and you've got **two** calls to `sc.nextInt()` inside that. The `while` loop looks like it'll only end when you type something that's not a number. It looks a lot like a copy/paste/editing error. I suggest you try printing out `number` after it was read, and the `stack` after the number was added to it - that will hopefully help you understand what's going on with your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies within your **while** loop, also the **for** loop is unnecessary. I made a few changes to your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements to place on the stack [1-10]:");
    int stackSize = sc.nextInt();
    Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

    System.out.println("Enter " + stackSize + " element(s):");
   
    int i = 0;
    while(i < stackSize){
        
            int number = sc.nextInt();
            stack.push(number);
            
            i++;
        }
    
    System.out.println(stack);            
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Enter the number of elements to place on the stack [1-10]:
 4
 Enter 4 element(s):
 4 3 3 4
 [4, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, very much appreciated. Sorry for not making it clear but my problem is I wanted to store multiple int values in a single line and store it in stack.

Comment: It works in that way too. Just input the values with a space in between. Check the output. I have made an edit to put values in a single line. Code is still the same